# Estou estudando Python e utilizando o Google colab como IDE. Ao utilizar \033[m, não encerra a colorização. Alguém pode ajudar?

Tags: python, cores, ansi

Estou aprendendo Python e utilizando o Google colab.
Então tentei.

```
print('\033[31mOlá Mundo!\033[m')
print('Olá Mundo!')
```

Oque acontece, é que o `\033[m` não encerra a colorização
e a linha seguinte  e todas as outras respostas também aparecem coloridas.

Testei em outra plataforma e funcionou.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Então. a partir daí, todas as respostas ficam vermelhas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que as cores voltem ao normal, basta executar o seguinte comando:

```
print('\033[31mOlá Mundo!\033[0m')
print('Olá Mundo!')
```

Repare que em minha solução eu adicionei o seguinte comando no final da string.

```
`\033[0m`
```

Eu apenas adicionei um `0 (zero)` no final do comando.

Comment: Obrigado. Sabia que estava no lugar certo.